# boost thread function arguments passed as reference (boost::ref() seems not to work...)

Tags: boost, boost-thread

I have the following simple function:

```
void hda(unsigned long &command)
{
    command++;
    PlugIn::gResultOut << "inside thread: " << command << std::endl;

return;
}
```

and I am creating a boost::thread as

```
void SU_HThread(unsigned long &command)
{
    command++,
    PlugIn::gResultOut << "before thread: " << command << std::endl;

    boost::thread Hthread = boost::thread(boost::bind(boost::move(hda), boost::ref(command)));

return;
}
```

But when I call this function, the command value, which is updated inside the thread is not registered...

```
number com = 0

SU_HThread(com) 
sleep(1) // sleep 1 second
result("after thread: "+com+" \n")
```

Output:

```
before thread: 1
inside thread: 2
after thread: 1
```

The usual answer with boost::ref(command) does not seem to work here.... 
Any ideas? Preferably without using promises, since I need to observe the change in command value in realtime.

thanks!

Comment: What happens when you join thread by `Hthread.join()` inside `SU_HThread` function ?

Comment: I am using these as wrapper functions for an external software. Using join on threads always freezes the software, even outside of this problem...

Comment: You are using `join` to wait for a result computed by thread, without `join` you have data race printing `com` because you don't know if thread is ended or not. I assume you call `sleep(1)` to give time for calulcation in thread ..